# WPF TreeView height changes when scrollbar appears

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have a TreeView in my WPF application. When we add items to the TreeView that cause the vertical scrollbar to appear and become enabled the height of the TreeView changes adding around 20px. This causes all controls below the TreeView to become pushed slightly off screen.

The TreeView is contained in a hierarchy that uses proportional scaling ("*" heights). I notice that if I set a fixed height the problem goes away. However for our application this isn't a practical solution.

Has anyone else seen the behaviour?

Comment: Post code of your layouts.

Comment: How the Vertical Scrollbar changes Height? you mean the vertical scrollbar shortens the usable width of the treeview and causes the Horizontal scrollbar to become visible?

Comment: @devhedgehog The layout code is huge and wouldn't be easy to paste into SO.

Comment: What are using around TreeView? A stackPanel?

Comment: I have a tree view which use a gird for each data template.